# How to apply multiple criteria to .Find?

Tags: excel, vba

I adapted code I found online.

- It finds the string "car" in column A and returns the rows as an array
- It assigns a variable to the length of the array (how many matches it found)
- It assigns a variable to generate a random number between 0 and the length of the array
- It then prints a random matching row's value into K3

```
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim msg As String

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Set c = .find("Car", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            ReDim Preserve myArray(y)
            myArray(y) = c.Row
            y = y + 1
            Set c = .findNext(c)
            If c Is Nothing Then
                GoTo DoneFinding
            End If
        Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If

DoneFinding:
End With

For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    msg = msg & myArray(x) & " "
Next x

ArrayLen = UBound(myArray) - LBound(myArray)

random_index = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, ArrayLen)

MsgBox myArray(random_index)

Dim test As String

test = "B" & myArray(random_index)

Range("K3").Value = Range(test)
```

Example
[image: example]

I'm struggling with adapting the find code to allow for multiple criteria. So in my example, it finds "Car". What if I want to find matches that had "Car" in column A and "Red" in column D?

I tried

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & "D1:D" & ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
     Set c = .find("Car", "Red", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

I get type mismatch on the Set line.

In case it is confusing, it currently looks for a string e.g. "Car" but I will eventually link this to the variable which will be assigned to a data validation list. So if the user chooses "car" from a drop down list, this is what it will search for.

Comment: I don't think `.Find` allows you to search with Multiple Criteria.

Comment: I wondered if there was another loop that could be put in that does individual 'finds' and if they all return true then it sets c (variable) like it does in the code in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Advancde Filter is something that fit your needs:

[image]

**Example Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Set CriteriaRange = ws.Range("A1", "E2")

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A4", "E" & LastRow)

    DataRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=CriteriaRange, Unique:=False
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAll()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

---

Edit according comment:

You can use the advanced filter and then loop through the filter results:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public CurrentRow As Long

Public Sub FilterData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Set CriteriaRange = ws.Range("A1", "E2")

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A4", "E" & LastRow)

    DataRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=CriteriaRange, Unique:=False
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAll()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    CurrentRow = 1
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


Public Sub GetNextResult()
    FilterData

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A4", "E" & LastRow)

    Dim FilteredData As Range
    Set FilteredData = DataRange.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If CurrentRow + 1 > FilteredData.Cells.Count Then
        CurrentRow = 1
    End If

    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Cell As Variant
    For Each Cell In FilteredData
        i = i + 1
        If i = CurrentRow Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Select
            'or
            'MsgBox Cell.Value & vbCrLf & Cell.Offset(0, 1) & vbCrLf & Cell.Offset(0, 2) & vbCrLf & Cell.Offset(0, 3) & vbCrLf & Cell.Offset(0, 4)
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm looking for it to return a single result that is different upon every button click (either random or in order of matches found, doesn't matter), however your demonstration of Advanced Filter is really useful to know and I think I might use it for something else in the same spreadsheet

Comment: @Sam You can use advanced filer and then loop through the filter result to get the next result only. See my edit.

Comment: So I'm using the MsgBox part of your GetNextResult sub, rather than the .Select ... What would be the best way to retain the result in the MsgBox but without physically altering the list that it pulls from. Currently, when I initiate GetNextResult, it filters the results to only show matches and then has a MsgBox - is it possible to leave the results visually unfiltered and only have the MsgBox?

Comment: @Sam No, you but you can remove the filter by running `ShowAll` right before you show the messagebox.

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thanks so much for your help. I've got this working with the data we used in the spreadsheet (vehicles, colour etc.) - I'm going to try and integrate it to my actual spreadsheet and hopefully it should all run in the same way

Comment: I'm still trying to troubleshoot the issue I've got now, but upon integrating it with my actual spreadsheet I'm having an issue where it's just cycling through all of the data range one by one, it doesn't seem to be looking at the Criteria Range and filtering properly. Am I right in thinking that I just change the CriteriaRange to be the row above the user selection?

Comment: No, it has to be exactly as in the example. The criteria range consists of the headers of the data and the data you want to filter for. So criteria range in the example consists of the green area.

Comment: Do the headers need to be in the same location as your example ie. A1 to E1? I've written the headers on J26, K26 and L26, and below that on J27, K27 and L27 I have the criteria that it should be searching for - but it doesn't seem to work

EDIT: I should note that I changed the CriteriaRange to ("J26", "L26")

Comment: Test, Google, Research: Keyword is "advanced filters"  there should be many tutorials about how to use them properly. I'm not very experienced in advanced filters.

Comment: Managed to figure it out, although occasionally it will return the result of the header but if you click it again it will cycle through the results, I'm still looking into how to resolve that.

I've been trying to figure out how to make it display an error if the match isn't found. I've tried wrapping the datarange.advancedfilter etc. in a On Error GoTo and then below putting a MsgBox but it seems to show that upon every execution of the code - any ideas?

Comment: @Sam check `FilteredData.Cells.Count` it shows how many rows are visible in the filtered data (incl. header).

Comment: So in this specific example, within the sub FilterData, at the end before it ends the Sub I have put MsgBox FilterData.Cells.Count (you put Filtered but I figured it was Filter as that's the name of the Sub?) and it returns Compile Error: Expected Function or variable

Comment: @Sam I wrote Filter**ed**Data not `FilterData`, find it in `GetNextResult`

Comment: I got it all to work but I have found it to be a bit buggy, sometimes when I execute the filter it will move elements on the sheet (like shapes) into different locations and that can cause some results to appear missing (but they're actually hidden), no idea how to resolve it, I've tried moving the criteria area into different locations to see if it was something like that but nothing has worked

Comment: I've moved some of the elements around so they're all above the filter and this seems to have solved the issue with elements moving or disappearing. With 'getnextresult', is it possible to include a counter? So each result it displays changes a textbox to the value of 1, and the next result goes to 2, and when it has cycled through all of the results and goes back to 1 the counter also goes back to 1? I've added a counter but I can't figure out how to make it reset when the filter goes back to result 1

Comment: @Sam Please open up a new question to ask something that was not in your original question. We cannot follow up answering new questions in comments. In the new question also include your attempt and explain where you got stuck or errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328291/including-a-counter-within-an-advanced-filter