# Including a counter within an advanced filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have an advanced filter set up and separate to that subroutine I have another subroutine that loops through the filter results and places the value into a text box. That all works fine but I'm trying to include a counter so for every result that's being displayed the counter goes up, and then when the criteria changes and new results are found it goes back to 1 and counts again from there.

```
Public Sub GetNextResult()
    FilterData

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")

    Dim header As String
    header = "txtbox1"

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A5", "H" & LastRow) 

    Dim FilteredData As Range
    Set FilteredData = DataRange.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If CurrentRow + 1 > FilteredData.Cells.Count Then
        CurrentRow = 1
    End If

    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Variant

    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 1

    For Each cell In FilteredData
        i = i + 1
        If i = CurrentRow Then
            Call ShowAll

            TextboxName = "txtbox1"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName).DrawingObject.Text = cell.Offset(0, 2)

            TextboxName2 = "txtbox2"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName2).DrawingObject.Text = cell.Offset(0, 3)

            TextboxName3 = "Cardcounter"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName3).DrawingObject.Text = counter

            If ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName).DrawingObject.Text = header Then
                'MsgBox "header detected"
                'Exit Sub
                Call GetNextResult
            End If

            Call quick_artwork

            counter = counter + 1

        Else
            Call ShowAll
            'Exit Sub
            'MsgBox "No data found matching this criteria"
            'TextboxName = "txtbox1"
            'ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName).DrawingObject.Text = "No data found matching this criteria"

            'TextboxName2 = "txtbox2"
            'ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName2).DrawingObject.Text = ""
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

So I've put `counter = 1` before the for loop and then within the for loop I've put `counter = counter + 1` and I thought that would work but it doesn't. It doesn't show an error, but the number doesn't change.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your subroutine is recursive, are you sure "counter" variable is not being reinitialized for each browsed row ?

Comment: Can you advise on where I should put the counter = counter + 1 for it to loop for as long as their are results in the filter?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `counter` outside the `GetNextResult()` routine, and set it to `1` before calling the `GetNextResult()` routine.

```
Dim counter As Integer

Sub SomeOtherSubCallingGetNextResult()
    ...
    counter = 1
    GetNextResult
    ...
End sub
```

Comment: And then assign the button that normally triggers getnextresult to the subroutine that defines the counter and calls getnextresult? Would I keep the + 1 in the getnextresult subroutine? How would it know to revert back to 1 when the results have been cycled through?

Comment: @Sam - Your question does not really talks about how `GetNextResult` is called. The `SomeOtherSubCallingGetNextResult` was just an example. You do not need to create another `Sub`, but change the code wherever `GetNextResult` is called.

Comment: There isn't another subroutine that calls GetNextResult. GetNextResult calls a subroutine called FilterData but not the other way round. GetNextResult is initiated by a user clicking on a macro button

Comment: @Sam - Then update your question with more context. Explain what you mean by "filter criteria change", by "results have been cycled through", etc.? All of this might be obvious to you, but not to others. Also, you did not say anything about how you indend to use the value of `counter`. How you want to use it, might have an impact on the answers.

Comment: The user selects from a couple of drop down data validation lists, there is an option to filter the data below so it shows only data that matches their selection. Separate to this, is getnextresult, which rather than visibly filtering the data, will filter it and insert a result into a text box upon each click. It calls another subroutine (‘showall’) so that the table is never visibly filtered. So every time a user clicks this button it is cycling through the results. But, it’s hard to know when you’re just looping, which is why I’m trying to add a counter. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Sam - You said: "So every time a user clicks this button it is cycling through the results.", this is where you need to reset the counter, Inside the button click event handler.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If it reset every time someone clicks the button then it'll never go past 1. I need to somehow tell the code that when it returns the first row for the second time then it should go back to 1

Comment: @Sam - Without seeing all relevant code, it is difficult to help you more.